# page.rb:220: warning: encountered \r in middle of line, treated as a mere space on Mac

Tags: ruby, selenium, rubygems, cucumber

I am trying to run a test in ruby cucumber, selenium webdriver, framework. The tests were written in windows machine and I am using Mac. I am getting the following error. I found at this Git hub link - https://github.com/rdoc/rdoc/pull/280 
that this can be fixed. I understood that I need to install "kpeg gem" which I did but it did not resolve the issue.

Could you please help? I want to know the steps to fix it incase you better understand the documentation on the link provided. I will greatly appreciate.

```
a3835233:astra yc98ag2$ cucumber --profile  pom_mcom_qa_new_ui --tags  @bat
/Users/yc98ag2/Documents/Git/astra/lib/new_ui/pages/mew2/catsplash_page.rb:220: warning: encountered \r in middle of line, treated as a mere space
/Users/yc98ag2/Documents/Git/astra/lib/new_ui/pages/mew2/dbconpage.rb:55: warning: encountered \r in middle of line, treated as a mere space
/Users/yc98ag2/Documents/Git/astra/lib/new_ui/pages/mew2/hpmb_add_mediagrp_id.rb:83: warning: encountered \r in middle of line, treated as a mere space
/Users/yc98ag2/Documents/Git/astra/lib/new_ui/pages/mew2/mew_promos_bcom.rb:161: warning: encountered \r in middle of line, treated as a mere space
/Users/yc98ag2/Documents/Git/astra/lib/pages/mew2/catsplash_page.rb:220: warning: encountered \r in middle of line, treated as a mere space
/Users/yc98ag2/Documents/Git/astra/lib/pages/mew2/dbconpage.rb:55: warning: encountered \r in middle of line, treated as a mere space
/Users/yc98ag2/Documents/Git/astra/lib/pages/mew2/hpmb_add_mediagrp_id.rb:83: warning: encountered \r in middle of line, treated as a mere space
/Users/yc98ag2/Documents/Git/astra/lib/pages/mew2/mew_promos_bcom.rb:161: warning: encountered \r in middle of line, treated as a mere space
including Capybara::DSL in the global scope is not recommended!
Warning: you should require 'minitest/autorun' instead.
Warning: or add 'gem "minitest"' before 'require "minitest/autorun"'
From:
  /Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
  /Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
  /Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  /Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
  /Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
  /Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  /Users/yc98ag2/Documents/Git/astra/features/step_definitions/oes_steps.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
  /Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
  /Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
  /Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
  /Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:95:in `load_code_file'
  /Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'
  /Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
  /Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
  /Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
  /Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:184:in `load_step_definitions'
  /Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:in `run!'
  /Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'
  /Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/bin/cucumber:13:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
  /Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
  /Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
  /Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test. From /Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit/testcase.rb:8:in `<module:Unit>'
undefined method `_run_suite' for class `Test::Unit::Runner' (NameError)
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:676:in `<class:Runner>'
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:261:in `<module:Unit>'
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:15:in `<module:Test>'
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/yc98ag2/Documents/Git/astra/features/step_definitions/oes_steps.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:95:in `load_code_file'
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:184:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:in `run!'
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/bin/cucumber:13:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/yc98ag2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

@Uri How can i tell looking at the following code that which lines have endings from windows style (\r\n).. for ex - the first line of error comes from the last line of this code which is sleep 5
Isn't there any workaround which makes it work for both windows and mac? coz i am working on a project in office where most of the guys are working on windows.

```
def click_verify_innerpool(table)
  Log.instance.info("Entering method: click_verify_max_innerpool_symbol()")
  sleep 5
  table.hashes.each do |hash|
    var1=hash['container']
    in_frame(:name => 'formframe') do |frame|
      Log.instance.debug("Inside the '"+$xpath['frm_frame']+"' frame")
      click_pool_sequence[var1]
      if var1=='MEW2_CS_MEN'
        for i in 1..3
          con_men_btn
          sleep 5

        end
      end
```

Answer (score 5):

From my experience, this issue also occurs when you copy&paste the code from somewhere. Re-typing a code from scratch should fix it.

How I was able to solve:

1. Copy & paste your code into some plain editor (I've used Mac's default text editor)
2. Clear formatting of the code (I switched to a plain mode)
3. Remove your file which has this issue
4. Create new file with same name
5. Copy & paste the code from your plain text editor and save

This should solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe the `\r` is the biggest problem in the stack you've shown us.

To get rid of the `\r`, open the offending files in you favorite text editor, and make sure to replace the line-endings from windows style (<kbd>\r\n</kbd>) to mac style (<kbd>\n</kbd>).

You also should read the other errors and warnings the stack trace tells you about:

> ```
> including Capybara::DSL in the global scope is not recommended!
> Warning: you should require 'minitest/autorun' instead.
> Warning: or add 'gem "minitest"' before 'require "minitest/autorun"'
> ```

and:

> ```
> MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test
> ```

Which will hopefully also fix the next issue, which is

> ```
> undefined method `_run_suite' for class `Test::Unit::Runner'
> ```

Comment: Do you recommend any solution for the other errors?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in Windows-style line endings (\r\n). You may see ^M endings in some text editors at the end of line.

On linux you may use dos2unix to repair line endings:

```
dos2unix /Users/yc98ag2/Documents/Git/astra/lib/new_ui/pages/mew2/catsplash_page.rb
```

On mac there is another solution:

```
mv catsplash_page.rb catsplash_page.rb.bak
cat catsplash_page.rb.bak | col -b > catsplash_page.rb
```